# C++ Mac Sierra 10.12.6 How to debug the error "<terminated> (exit value:-1)" in eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, gdb, macos-sierra

I've spent my whole night trying to figure out why my program would terminate in the middle. I'm using Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.0 in Sierra 10.12.6.

When running the program, it gives me " (exit value:-1)" error. I threw in some cout debug and I saw the program just simply wouldn't go on in the middle of a readFile() function I wrote, right after `ifstream infile(filename.c_str(),ios::in);` . I tried to use the debug function but it always gives me "During startup program terminated with signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap." error. I googled it and in Stackoverflow people say it is specific to Mac Sierra. I've upgraded and code-signed the gdb.

But now, is there any option I can go on to identify and solve this terminate problem?

Thanks,
Sincerely